# entity framework 6 and database first

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I have searched in different forums about T4 and EF6, but cant figure out properly how to do a database first approach in visual studio 2013 using entity framework 6.
When I try to add a ADO.NET entity data model it creates an empty .edmx file.
Is it even possible to do a database first approach using visual studio 2013 and EF6?
Would really appreciate any help.

If I follow the steps mentioned here  asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-developm‌​ent/… visual studio community edition is only generating empty edmx file.
Please note I have a vs 2013 community edition.

Note: Thanks a lot for all below who tried to help.
For downvoters -
If you can not help then please try not show your superiority by down voting the question. Of late, stackoverflow is full of self appointed moral polices who only want to downvote others to keep their ratings higher.

Comment: A google search resulted me in this, maybe it helps https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database

Comment: Are you choosing the database that you want to use for your project? Or are you going to add the entities manually?

Comment: do a right click on the empty model (edmx file in designer mode) and select the option to generate a model based on a database.

Comment: Thanks Bas for the link ... I had already followed these steps  and it takes you to this link https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application.But visual studio community edition is only generating empty edmx file.

Comment: BviLLe_Kid , I am choosing the database and using Visual studio community 2013.

Comment: magicandre1981, I tried that already and it creates .tt files and empty .edmx file. maybe it has something to do with Visual studio 2013 community editio?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this finally and posting it here if it of any help to anyone else.
What I figured out that you cannot use entity framework 6 with Visual studio 2013 community edition to generate .edmx file with DB entity diagrams.
I had to uninstall EF6 from my solution and then retry to add the database again. This time Visual studio grave me an option of selecting EF5 - which did the trick.